# Pimcore: What are examples of Multi-Channel-Publishing?

Tags: pimcore

So there is this question

```
Question 3: What are examples of Multi-Channel-Publishing?
   a) Delivering content from a headless CMS to a digital kiosk via GrapQL APIs.
   b) Providing the right content to your audiences on multiple channels.
   c) Personalizing order management in the Pimcore backend.
   d) Automatically sending a product sheet PDF based on live PIM data to partners.
```

Since it asks for examples,  `b` is not the case, since it's a feature description, it's not an example.
In my reasoning the correct answer is `d` because it the feature implies some data filtering and output to different channels, but it doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: SO is not here to give you test solutions. Please refrain from such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is everything except `Personalizing order management`. Thank you all, thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

Example of Multi-Channel-Publishing are: **Personalizing order management**